# Format specifiers for VB.NET in Visual Studio in 2013

Tags: vb.net, immediate-window, command-window, debug-print

I've been trying to find a way to render \r\n as actual newlines in the immediate and command window in my VB.NET 4.5.1 application.  I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868862/newlines-in-the-immediate-window) which teaches about the `nq` specifier, but it appears to apply only to C#. In VB.NET, `nq` doesn't even appear to work because I get `Expression expected` printed back out at me.

Is there a different way to make newlines actually show as separate lines in the immediate or command window in VB.NET?

Comment: @leppie Why did you remove the VS 2013 tag?

Comment: VB.NET does not support format specifiers.  That's where that ends, use the Text Visualizer instead.  Looks like a spy glass icon.

Comment: VB will also print `\r\n` as `"\r\n"`.  use `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: @HansPassant I know of the spy glass icon when I want to use the text visualizer while debugging variable/property values, but I need this specifically for the command/immediate windows.  I've check both and see no such icon.  FYI, I created a helper method that is meant to be called only from the immediate/command windows.  The return string may have newlines, so I need to capture those as well.

Comment: FWIW, the output window converts like you want  (`Console.WriteLine(...)`)

Comment: Write your own sub() to convert the desired characters?

Comment: @Plutonix It's a webforms app, not a console app.  I did try `Console.WriteLine()` thinking it might show up in the output window, but it just says `Expression does not produce a value.`

Answer (score 1):

An easier way in visual studio 2015 is to do this in the debug window:

```
?string,nq
```

You can also do the debug version in earlier versions of VS

```
?System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(string,nq)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that the solution is to use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print()`.  To reproduce the original issue, entering this into the Immediate window...

`? "a" & vbCrLf & "a"`

...just returns this:

`"a  a"`

However, using this...

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("a" & vbCrLf & "a")`

...actually shows the newline:

```
a
a
```