# How Visual Studio Immediate Windows to print format indented JSON?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I tried to use `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows, Formatting.Indented)` to convert variable to json when debugging, but vs immediate only show non-format string like image

[image]

I expect to get result like below LINQPad's result
[image]

Comment: With immediate window you get result that you can copy-paste and it will be valid code. Add `Console.WriteLine` to display string with indentation

Comment: @JL0PD I try `Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows, Formatting.Indented))` and it show `Expression has been evaluated and has no value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'm not using immediate window because find it less useful than other options.

To inspect value you can hover over variable and click on magnifier icon, it will display stored data with `ToString()` representation. Optionally you can choose other visualizer like `json`, `xml` or `html` with dropdown near icon. Downside is that you need declared variable.

[image]

Other option is to use `Watch` panel (during debug click `debug -> windows -> watch -> watch 1`). It allows you to inspect variables, override them and call methods

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted this, but it need to inject code into project. emm.. it looks like the better answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to print newline and tab characters, you can type the variable name into the Immediate Window followed by the string ",nq".

So instead of typing `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows, Formatting.Indented)` into the Immediate Window, you would type `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows, Formatting.Indented),nq`.

The ",nq" at the end serves as a "format specifier" for the Immediate Window. Find out more about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/debugger/format-specifiers-in-csharp?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Thanks to user [davesem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/346674/davesem) for pointing this out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868862/newlines-in-the-immediate-window).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be saving json to file, it will greatly help to analyze and compare different outputs

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\debug_file.json", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tSet, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
```