# Deserialize response from TDAmeritrade API

Tags: c#, api, serialization

I have an api call i make to refresh token from TDAmeritrade that comes back in following format:

```
"{\n  \"access_token\" : \"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
3XSynTxRDvSNISLcfW1HxcIaAhv+xaUUC2oNV3kZIHPmMiggOIWM9Mh7HztgOV1oSuDuC6TSdXtnBxyBjZTlGwuOfbAmqDkYnycjTpGEdnx5/fO4IlFLWqPViDaqTA9fcasV5lU83/IXOQ4WdmIcWe8gows9CQRnwWV/A=212FD3x19z9sWBHDJACbC00B75E\",\n  \"scope\" : \"PlaceTrades AccountAccess MoveMoney\",\n  \"expires_in\" : 1800,\n  \"token_type\" : \"Bearer\"\n}"
```

Here is my class that i am trying to deserialize into:

```
public class TokenResponse {
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("scope")]
    public string Scope { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
}
```

I try to deserialize like following which works for all my other purposes of deserializing:

```
var str = [string pasted above];
var tokenResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TokenResponse>(str);
```

I tried using HttpUtility.HtmlDecode
I can parse out access_token if i have to but would prefer not to

Comment: You mention trying deserialization which works in other cases. How does that method fail you now?

Comment: Is it possible the JSON is malformed? Why do you have new line characters in there? ( `\n`)

Comment: So those /n are in the response which i found odd.  By failing it just has object with null properties

Comment: What if you tried `str = str.Replace("\n","");` right before your deserialization?

Comment: @Ibrennan208 Yes i tried that. Same result

Comment: Where did you get this JSON string? Is the JSON string from the output window in VS?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410924/how-visual-studio-immediate-windows-to-print-format-indented-json